# Creating a new session Bean in javaee6

Tags: eclipse, java-ee-6, stateless-session-bean

Please, I tried to add a simple session Bean to my javaee6 project and when I right clicked on the project->EJB->session Bean as shown on this link:

[image]

and clicked next, I got to the next link:

[image]

Everything was ok but i can't add the project's name. The drop down box is not clickable, and when I clicked on the source folder's text area, and clicked the Browse button, it didn't work as well.I have tried all I could to add the project's name but to no avail. Could anyone tell me why this is so?

Thanks

Comment: Hello @Darwin, how were you able to add the pix to the question? thanks

Comment: Using the image button or pushing `CTRL+G` on your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the project, select Properties. Click on “Project Facets” and click “Convert to faceted form”.
Check the “EJB Module” and select the version as 3.0 or 3.1